# What is the difference between "*.pl" and *.pl in grep? Why does quoting change the result?

Tags: shell, grep, wildcards, quoting

What is the difference between:
`grep "string" . -r  --include *.pl`

and

`grep "string" . -r  --include "*.pl"`

The latter includes files in subdirectoried while the former not. Why?

Comment: The difference isn't in `grep`; it's in the shell.  `grep` never sees the quotes.

Answer (score 18):

The `*` (star, or asterisk) is a special character which is (usually) interpreted by the shell before it is given the command. It is (usually) expanded to all filenames except those with leading dots. See the [bash manual about pattern matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching) for more information.

If placed in quotes the star will not be interpreted by the shell and is given to the command verbatim.

---

Examples explained. The quoted one:

```
grep "string" . -r --include "*.pl"
```

Here `grep` will receive the option `--include` with the argument `*.pl`. That is a 4 character string starting with the character `*`. What `grep` does with that string is entirely up to `grep`. In this case `--include` means to only consider files matching the glob `*.pl`.

AFAIK behind the scenes gnu grep uses the same pattern matching lib as gnu bash. That means it will include the same files as shown by `echo *.pl`.

The not quoted one:

```
grep "string" . -r --include *.pl
```

Here the shell will first expand the glob `*.pl` before executing the command. The glob will expand to all filenames ending in `.pl`.

Suppose there are the files `foo.pl`, `bar.pl` and `baz.pl`. After expanding the glob the command line looks like this:

```
grep "string" . -r --include foo.pl bar.pl baz.pl
```

Here `grep` will receive the option `--include` with the argument `foo.pl`, followed by the options `bar.pl` and `baz.pl`.

`--include foo.pl` instructs grep to only consider files matching the pattern `foo.pl`. Since there are no wildcards (no stars) in the pattern the only file matching that will be the file named `foo.pl`.

The options `bar.pl` and `baz.pl` instructs grep to also search in those files. But since they do not match the pattern `foo.pl` they will be ignored as required by the previous `--include`.

Comment: This is a great observation. I always wondered why `grep -r` seemed inconsistent but never noticed it was only when I used a `*`.

Answer (score 6):

The difference is that if you don't quote the pattern (`*.pl`) it is expanded by the shell. For example, if you run your `grep` in a directory that contains a file called `foo.pl`, since the `*pl` is expanded by the shell, what `grep` actually sees is:

```
grep "string" . -r --include foo.pl
```

Since you tell it to only include `foo.pl` it will only search through that one file.

If you quote your pattern, the shell will *not* expand it and `grep` gets the correct command, namely

```
 grep "string" . -r --include *pl
```