# Grep all the files that end with a particular extension and also contain a particular string

Tags: grep, filenames

I have some .sh and .bat files in a directory. I want to list only the .sh files that has the word "JAVA_HOME".

I tried `grep -rl "JAVA_HOME" | grep "*.sh"`, `grep -rl "JAVA_HOME" *.sh` and few other random things, but none of them worked. Can someone help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/185951/117549 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/82139/117549 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/336921/117549 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/500243/117549 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/14498/117549 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/7383/117549

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you appear to be using GNU grep already (with `-r`), add the `--include` option to search only those matching filenames:

```
grep -rl --include='*.sh' "JAVA_HOME"
```